# How to auto generate the with... type method in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is it possible to generate the `with...` type method with IntelliJ for Scala?

Example:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

I would like to find the tool to auto-generate the method of type:

```
def withName(name: String): Person = this.copy(name=name)

def withAge(age: Int): Person = this.copy(age=age)
```

is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing out-of-the-box, but you can create a scala template of your own:

1. Select Settings/Preferences | Editor | Live Templates.
2. From options on the right, open the list of Scala templates.
3. Click + to add a new template.

You can see an example [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/edit-scala-code.html#7db8a039)

Answer (score 2):

I you want to auto-generate these methods rather than writing them explicitly (even with an IntelliJ template), you can do that with an annotation macro that will run at compile-time.

In particular, you can check the [scalameta](https://scalameta.org) project for informations about this. Note however that macros are an experimental feature that is likely to change in trivial ways when Scala 3 is released. In my opinion, you should think hard about whether writing `withName(name)` rather than `copy(name=name)` is worth the trouble of defining all these methods (whether its manually, through IntelliJ snippets, or using macros), and only go for macros if it will save you a lot of trouble down the line.